# Object.Assign on Composite Object

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I'm having problems with references when I try to copy/clone an object into a variable and then, change values of one and don't affect the another one.

I've been having a look into the doc of [`Object.Assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) method, and I tried what the have for deep clone unsuccessfully.

I created a plnkr in order to express myself better and in case you know how to do it properly.

[Code Sample in here](https://plnkr.co/edit/x9AylsV9jaab28jrIWRp?p=preview)

```js
const value = 20.20;
let a = { a: 10 };
let bb = { v: value };
let b = { b: 20, bb: bb };
let c = { c: 30 };
let object1 = { name: 'cloneObject', a, b, c }
let object2 = Object.assign({}, object1);
let object3 = Object.assign({}, object1);

object1.name = 'it works fine';
object1.b.bb.v = 999; // this will change same property in object2 & object3 and it shouldn't

document.getElementById('expected1').innerHTML = object1.b.bb.v;
document.getElementById('expected2').innerHTML = value;
document.getElementById('expected3').innerHTML = value;


document.getElementById('name1').innerHTML = object1.name;
document.getElementById('name2').innerHTML = object2.name;
document.getElementById('name3').innerHTML = object3.name;

document.getElementById('value1').innerHTML = object1.b.bb.v;
document.getElementById('value2').innerHTML = object2.b.bb.v;
document.getElementById('value3').innerHTML = object3.b.bb.v;
```

```html
<table style="width:100%; text-align: center">
  <tr>
    
    <th>Object</th>
    
    <th>Name</th>
    
    <th>Value</th>
    
    <th>Expected Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Object 1</td>
    <td id='name1'></td>
    <td id='value1'></td>
    <td id='expected1'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Object 2</td>
    <td id='name2'></td>
    <td id='value2'></td>
    <td id='expected2'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Object 3</td>
    <td id='name3'></td>
    <td id='value3'></td>
    <td id='expected3'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

With @czosel answer, I got:

`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object1));`

So it would looks like this:

```
  let object1 = {name: 'cloneObject', a, b, c}
  let object2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object1));
  let object3 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object1));
```

I find @gon250 answer better, as I'm going to implement it in the parent class and it will inheritance the method by default. I think recursiveness will be more efficient.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below you can see a simple function to clone an object:

```
function cloneObject(myObj) {
    var temp = myObj.constructor();
    if (myObj === null || typeof myObj !== 'object') {
        return myObj;
    }
    for (var key in myObj) {
        temp[key] = cloneObject(myObj[key]);
    }
    return temp;
}
```

here is an example implementing the function into your code:

https://jsfiddle.net/gon250/4qx247th/

Answer (score 1):

`Object.assign` doesn't do deep cloning, see [Warning for Deep Clone (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Deep_Clone).

For alternatives, please see [this popular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript).